# definition macro implementation in C

Tags: c

I have these definitions in a project_conf.h file

```
#define MCU  16F628
#define MCU_HEADER_FILE   MCU##.h
```

And I want to implement a macro that would substitute this line

```
#include <MCU_HEADER_FILE>
```

with just

```
CALL_MUC_HEADER_FILE
```

These `<>` things I dont know how to handle.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Why obfuscate your code even more?

Comment: Look [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Computed-Includes.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart that you can't effectively define macro, that contains `#include` directive, that is something like:

```
#define FOO #include <foo.h>
```

there is another issue with these macro definitions:

```
#define MCU  16F628
#define MCU_HEADER_FILE   MCU##.h
```

The second *object-like* macro is invalid, since it does not produce valid *preprocessing token*. The `##` operator concatenates token `MCU` (not even expanding it) with `.`, which combines into `MCU.`, invoking an *undefined behavior*.

Regarding to C11 (N1570) §6.10.3.3/p3 *The `##` operator*:

> If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is
>   undefined.

For instance, GCC compiler has diagnostic message in such case, when you run it with `-E` flag:

> check.c:7:1: error: pasting "MCU" and "." does not give a valid
>   preprocessing token

You can also see from here, that `MCU` was not expanded into its text replacement.

The valid solution would be to get rid off `##` operator at all and apply third, less-known form of `#include` directive:

> `# include` *pp-tokens new-line*

Here is one possible way:

```
#define MCU_HEADER <MCU.h> // MCU will be expanded into 16F628
#include MCU_HEADER
```

But as stated above it best what you can do with `#define` directive as is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you are thinking too complicated.

The tokens after an `#include` directive are simply expanded, you don't need to do any macro concatenation magic with it:

```
#define incFile(A) A.h
#define hoho(X) <incFile(X)>
#include hoho(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: the MCU_HEADER_FILE definition should be changed to include the < and > on either side

```
#define GLUE_IMPL(A, B) A##B
#define GLUE(A, B) GLUE_IMPL(A, B)
#define MCU 16F628
#define MCU_HEADER_FILE   GLUE(GLUE(GLUE(<, MCU),.h), >)

#include MCU_HEADER_FILE
```

You can't put anything in a `#define` statement that begins with a `#` (`#include`, `#if`, `#endif` e.t.c.), so `#include MCU_HEADER_FILE` is the best you can get.

Comment: Macros aren't expanded within `<...>` in a `#include` directive. You can do `#include MCU_HEADER_FILE`; the `<` and `>` would have to be part of the macro expansion.

Comment: @KeithThompson-amended:)

Comment: It even doesnt work this way: #define HEADER_FILE 16F628.h
#include <HEADER_FILE> The compiler spits the error: file HEADER_FILE can not be found, so the HEADER_FILE seems not to be expanded at all. It seems that the include directive accepts the macro definition literally (not expanded to 16f628.h)

Comment: @RadoslawKrasimirow - I put some code in my answer which worked for me in MSVC

Comment: @RadoslawKrasimirow - the `#define HEADER_FILE 16F628.h #include <HEADER_FILE>` didn't work because HEADER_FILE is not exapnded between the < and >; it just thinks that you want a file called 'HEADER_FILE'. to resolve that, try `#define HEADER_FILE <16F628.h> #include HEADER_FILE`

Comment: This will not work with most C compilers because the concatenation is illegal -- the result of a concatenation must be a single valid preprocessing token.